# What is the difference between sortedDescending() and sortedByDescending()?

Tags: kotlin, collections

In this block of code,

```
fun getList(): List<Int> {
    return arrayListOf(1, 5, 2).sortedDescending()
}
```

Why can't I do

```
fun getList(): List<Int> {
    return arrayListOf(1, 5, 2).sortedByDescending()
}
```

instead?

If I'm applying the method wrong to that ArrayList, what would a correct usage of `sortedByDescending()` look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to think about it is that `sortDescending()` is applied to an **ArrayList of elements like integers or strings**, but `sortedByDescending()` is applied to an **ArrayList of elements that have properties that we wish to sort-by**.

Example:
In this block of code, you are simply sorting a list of integers.

```
fun getList(): List<Int> {
    return arrayListOf(1, 5, 2).sortedDescending()
}
```

In this next line of code, `sortByDescending()` **requires us to pass an argument,** indicating the property that we want to sort by.

```
fun getList(): List<Object> {
    val list = ArrayList<CustomObject>()
    list.add(CustomObject("Z"))
    list.add(CustomObject("A"))
    list.add(CustomObject("B"))

    return list.sortedByDescending(object.property)
}
```

**[This](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-sort)** is a good source for information on sorting overall.

Comment: `return arrayListOf(1, 5, 2).sortedByDescending{it}`

works

Answer (score 1):

Look here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html

Click on the functions in order to explore some more details.

Comment: I tried looking there before I asked the question, because I was trying to look for array comparators. The syntax seems pretty dense and I wasn't able to understand it, so I asked here

Comment: No problem, I just hope people coming here from somewhere else find this useful : )